# Resetting Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, chromebook, reset

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 on my Chromebook and want to know how i would reset it to when I first got it or factory mode. I want to do this because I am trying to install android studio, but nothing is working so I am going to see if resetting it, will help.

Comment: Did the Chromebook come preinstalled with Ubuntu? if so I'd check the docs that came with it.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the only way to 'reset' Ubuntu 14.04 to the purest defaults is to do a full reinstall of the operating system, overwriting your old data and repartition the drive.  There's no other 'factory settings reset' option that I am aware of.

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: @NoahHornak However you installed Ubuntu the first time, just follow the same steps again.